# What are some good examples of post-processing edge detection?

Tags: opengl, directx11, post-processing, edge-detection

I'm trying to implement a post-processing pass to detect silhouette-edges from depth data.
(by silhouette-edge of a triangles mesh I mean the triangle edges shared by a front and a back-facing triangle relative to the view direction, see image below).
[image]

From the little research I've done, most of the methods used in games and 3d applications are based on finding the gradient of the eye Z coordinate in image space and then processing the values trying to isolate the silhouette-edges.

Since I'm working for a CAD project, silhouettes need to be as precise as possible, while it looks to me that, with the methods mentioned above, the more accurate/sensitive your filter, the more artifacts are introduced (i.e. entire surfaces detected as edges when you look edge-on on something that extends far along the Z).

Besides, one should carefully choose weights and tolerances for those algorithms.

**What are some good examples of silhouette detection in post-processing in commercial products/game?**

Specifically, I'd like to find something to compare my experiments against, and also to see the limitations of post-processing edge detection in a state-of-the-art application.

Are there other algorithms for post-processing edge detection as alternatives to Sobel/Roberts cross/...?

Comment: I happened across this shader toy the other day. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/DslXz2

Comment: Hi, Leone! While this is a very interesting topic, asking for examples/resources is specifically off-topic (no "right answer"). Is it possible for you to edit the question to be something with an objective answer? Like a specific flaw in your results or a question about a specific algorithm? I'm not sure what to do here, but in it's current form this question probably needs to be closed.

Comment: Thanks @luserdroog for pointing that out. I'll open a new question, after some more testing.